# iOS Charts extra space and adding x-axis labels

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I have been using iOS [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) to create a bar graph. This is what I have so far:

[image] .

I am having trouble achieving three things:

- Changing the x-axis labels from (0-7) to Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.
- Getting rid of the labels above the bars (1.0, 10.0, 20, etc.)
- How to get rid of the space between the bars and the axis at the very bottom

Help with any one of these would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please share your code.

For problem number 1:

```
 var xvalues: [String] = [String]()

 for i in 0 ..< datapoints.count {               
    xvalues.append("custom text here")
 }

 barchartview.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: xvalues)
```

For problem number 2:

```
    let dataSet = BarChartDataSet()
    dataSet.values = barChartDataEntries

    // to hide values above the bars
    dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false        

    let data = BarChartData(dataSet: dataSet)
    barchartview.data = data
```

Answer (score 5):

Please check below:

Changing the x-axis labels from (0-7) to Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc. :

```
var weekdays: [String] = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: weekdays)
```

Getting rid of the labels above the bars (1.0, 10.0, 20, etc.) :

```
let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
```

For lining bars to the xAxis :

```
barChartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
```

Comment: When there is already another answer with the same solution you are using to problems 1 and 2 and you add minor things (an array and a solution to the 3rd problem). You should consider editing the answer that´s already there.

Comment: The solution for lining the bars worked perfectly, thanks for sharing. Maybe I'm just being dumb but this library isn't very well documented..

Comment: Thank you for the answer to question 3. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
lineChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: weekdays)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding a short explanation to your answer. StackOverflow is a site to help people further in their skills, and not just a codesharing platform. Leaving an explanation helps them understand how to solve the problem.